# unordered_map insertion fails

Tags: c++, unordered-map, nullptr

**Note:** I spent a lot of time trying to understand where my problem was coming from. However, as I was writting this post, I found the solution to my problem. Yet, I think it is still worth posting it. Besides, I am not 100% sure about my interpretation.

---

Here is my simplified problem with a simple example.

`matrix` is a sparse representation of a **binary matrix**. In this example I chose:

1 0
1 1
0 0
1 1

Each column is represented by a `set<int>`, giving the indices of the non-zero elements. For instance, for the first column of the matrix, lines of indices {0,1,3} are non-zero.

**Objective of the algorithm**:

- For each column, find the highest index on that column (for instance, 3 for the first column), see if some column **has already been inserted** in the `highestMapToColumns` unordered_map.
- Then in case a column is found, perform some operations on the column. No operations is performed here though, for the sake of clarity.
- Finally, add the pair `(highestIndex,column)` to the unordered map `highestMapToColumns`.

`

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector<set<int>* >* matrix = new vector<set<int>* >();
    int column1[]= {0,1,3};
    int column2[]= {1,3};
    matrix->push_back(new set<int>(column1,column1+3));
    matrix->push_back(new set<int>(column2,column2+2));

    unordered_map<int, set<int>* > highestMapToColumns;
    int highestIndex = -1;
    for(vector<set<int>* >::iterator iteratorOnColumns = matrix->begin();iteratorOnColumns!=matrix->end();iteratorOnColumns++){
        while(true){
            if((*iteratorOnColumns)->size() == 0){
                highestIndex = -1;
                break;
            }
            highestIndex = *((*iteratorOnColumns)->rbegin());
            cout<<"Attempting to get index : "<<highestIndex<<endl;
            set<int>* toSubstract = highestMapToColumns[highestIndex];
            if (toSubstract != nullptr) {
                cout<<"Column found !!"<<endl;
                break;
            }else{ 
                cout<<"Column not found"<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(highestIndex != -1){
            cout<<"Attempting to insert index : "<<highestIndex<<endl;
            highestMapToColumns.insert(make_pair(highestIndex, (*iteratorOnColumns)));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** of this program:

```
Attempting to get index : 3
Column not found
Attempting to insert index : 3
Attempting to get index : 3
Column not found
Attempting to insert index : 3
```

The first *"Column not found"* output is normal since nothing was inserted in the unordered map, however, the second is not.

I inserted a breakpoint and debugged at the moment of the insertion. I observed that `*iteratorOnColumns` was not a nullptr, and that it was pointing to the expected `set<int>` representing column1.

There must be a problem of insertion...

Comment: Also, why so many pointers? Wouldn't `vector<set<int>> matrix;` do just fine, and simplify the code a lot?

Comment: Totally ! I chose that originally but changed it thinking that it could be the origin of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

**If I understood correctly :**

The problem comes from the fact that when I attempt to find a column in the unordered_map `highestMapToColumns`, with the given key `highestIndex`, it inserts the pair `(highestIndex,nullptr)`, and this prevents any further insertion of the same key in the map...

Therefore `highestMapToColumns`, will only return the `nullptr` which is the first value inserted with the key `highestIndex`.

Comment: Use the `find` member method instead to check if an associative container contains an element, without inserting it automatically. `if(set.find(elem) != set.end()) ...`